# How to hide columns GridView when AutoGenerateColumns = "true"?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using an `Asp:GridView` with `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to **true** to display all the fields.
But I am struck with a problem here.
I need to show only few columns not all..but I do not know them until run-time, like which fields to bind.

So, There are 2 sets of columns coming for me one with Prefix B_ and the other with Prefix R_
I need to show either B_ or R_ based on the radio button selection.

But I do not want to make separate call to the DB on radio button selection, So I am pulling all the data at once, when I am binding to the grid.

But the problem as I said it is showing all the columns but initially I want the grid to display only columns with prefix B_

Is there a way can I achieve this, Please do help me..

Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend loading them into two different sets of objects, and changing the value of the <del>ItemsSource</del> DataSource property when different radio button values are selected.

EDIT: Replaced ItemsSource with DataSource, getting my ASP.NET and WPF mixed up.

Comment: I was thinking of making columns invisible in either the DataBound event or the Page.PreRender, but I like this idea better.